# Understanding Mortgaged Backed Security during financial crisis

Tags: financial-economics, financial-markets, financial-crises

This is my understanding of the mortgage backed security.Banks will give loans to customers, and then they decide to sell the loans to investment banks and charge a fee with it to earn profit. Now the investment banks will be earning the principal amount as well as the interest. But since, investment banks are not in the business of servicing loans or keeping loans on balance sheet, they create a special purpose entity. All mortgage payments will now go to this entity.

Now since, its a new entity and will be earning good amount of money through interest every year, investors will be willing to invest in this new entity. Investment bank also knows this and hence they issue shares

This is what happened during the financial crisis according to what I understood. But here is the question
If the sub prime lenders and prime lenders default, how is it going to impact the share price.
Also, let's say the share prices go down because people default and they aren't able to pay the interest rate then how is it going to impact the investment banks. Investment banks have already earned the money by selling the shares
My third question is, why are these shares being called mortgage backed securities? The home owners are not buying these shares, it is the investors who are buying the shares. So let's say tomorrow company decides to sell the shares, how is that going to impact the home owner?

Comment: Hi:  As you know, the whole MBS process is involved, so it's probably best to read Frank Fabozzi's big book on MBS. ( I assume it's still around ). Just to be brief, there are no shares allocated by the investment bank.  The MBS are sold kind of like bonds but with prepayment risk or are put in a layer of a CMO. There was a shorter red book called fixed income mathematics that also might be of help. I'll go on amazon and see if I can get the links.

Comment: The cover changed but this is the first book I was referring to above. https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Fixed-Income-Securities-Eighth/dp/0071768467/ref=sr_1_13?dchild=1&keywords=fixed+income+mathematics&qid=1627382837&sr=8-13

Comment: I'm not one hundred percent sure because the cover used to be red but this might be the second one I was referring to.  https://www.amazon.com/Fixed-Income-Mathematics-Analytical-Statistical/dp/B01JXUYTHW/ref=sr_1_12?dchild=1&keywords=fixed+income+mathematics&qid=1627382922&sr=8-12

Comment: @markleeds Hey, I will try to simplify my question. Suppose lenders have to pay 1 billion dollar to investment banks at 10% rate of interest. So the investment bank set up a special purpose entity and issue shares to get the amount quickly as they dont want to wait for 15-20 years for lenders to pay loans. Now suppose the lenders default, due to which the share prices of entity will go down. Then how is that going to make an investment bank bankrupt, they already raised the required capital by issuing shares. Why then US government had to bailout JP Morgan and other investment banks

Comment: Money was already raised by shares, so even if the prices go down that wont impact the company right? How is this going to impact lenders?

Comment: Harshita: Hopefully someone else can answer your question in more detail because I'm not following most of it and don't have the expertise nor the time to understand. What I can say is this. Once an invesentment bank gets the mortgages from fannie mae or wherever, they pool them and make a security called an MBS. There are many of the securities ( just like bonds ) Now, some people buy an MBS ( call it MBS A)  from the investment bank ( they receive some coupon rate every month )  and some other ( MBS B, MBS C, MBS D etc )  are also held by the investment bank and waiting to be sold.

Comment: Continued: Now, Ii the loans behind that MBS ( the loans were pooled to make the MBS ) stop being paid by the people who took out the loans, then those MBS  ( the B, the C, the D etc ) become worthless or atleast lose a lot of their value. This is what happened during the crisis. The banks had a lot of these MBS securities on their books so,, when the mortgages stpped being paid, the value of the respective MBS took a dive. I strongly suggest taking a look at the books I linked to. They give nice overviews of the MBS market as far as what's going on behind the scenes.